# How to get the principal name after authentication

Tags: spnego, gssapi

Using MIT gss-api libraries, I've written a C program which gets as an input the full Negotiate token and performs the kerberos authentication (using keytab on the server side). The program successfully calls `gss_acquire_cred` and then `gss_accept_sec_context` and I'm able to create the context and get back the client token.

Now, how can I get the client principal name / user name? I thought that maybe calling `krb5_build_principal` is the right way but I don't see how to get all the input parameters for this function

Comment: Did you answer help?

Answer (score 0):

As you as you have a context handle on the acceptor side, you can call[`gss_inquire_context`](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=gss_inquire_context&apropos=0&sektion=3&manpath=FreeBSD+10.2-RELEASE&arch=default&format=html) to inquire for the `src_name` who initiated (your client) the context or you request [`gss_accept_sec_context`](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=+gss_accept_sec_context&apropos=0&sektion=3&manpath=FreeBSD+10.2-RELEASE&arch=default&format=html) directly to return that value. Sample code available on request.